# Doctrine2: Filtering by ManToMany Association

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I want to retrieve a collection of objects based on what they are associated to. For example, by a category. This would be a Many to Many relationship.

I've been able to achieve that with MEMBER OF, however I need to pass in an array of IDs, opposed to one at a time. I see there is an "IN ()", but it seems to require a subquery, which I would like to avoid.

MEMBER OF example:
`SELECT o FROM Entity\Object1 o WHERE 'CATEGORY_CODE' MEMBER OF o.categories`

(Edit)
This is what I would like to do, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding how entities work in DQL:
`SELECT o FROM Entity\Object1 o WHERE o.categories.Id IN (id, id, id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT o FROM Entity\Object1 o JOIN o.categories c WHERE c.id in ('id', 'id', 'id');
```

If this isn't what you want, you'll have to edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do it without the join? (Updated my question with desired query)

Comment: not without a subquery, which you said you didn't want in the original question.  Why don't you want a join?

Comment: It requires a little more leg work to generate the DQL statements through an API I'm building. I'll need to detect if the property is actually a joined table, opposed to a property and generate the join from there.  

In addition, I'm unsure what implications calling a JOIN on an object that already has mapping for that relationship will do. Does it become a partial object? Does it have a performance hit? These questions go out of scope of my original question, so I can repost if needed.

Comment: The join would return all relevant objects.   So for a object1 with three categories, you would get four objects (object1 plus three categories).  It is somewhat difficult for me to conceptualize the 'detect if a property is actually a joined table', if you join on a property that is not a table, it will just fail.  However, that data is readily available in class metadata if you must go by this approach.  As for performance hit, I don't have any data.